# Programmatically change attributed title of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to programmatically change the title of an `UIButton` which has an attributed title.
The button is created in IB. I do not want to change the attributes just the title/text.

I've tried the code below but cannot find a way to change the title of the `NSAttributedString`.

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [self.deleteButton attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal];

// How can I change title of attributedString without changing the attributes?

[self.deleteButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Partially you have the answer.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[_ deleteButton attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal]];

[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) withString:@"Your new string"];

[_ deleteButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Instead of creating `NSAttributedString` create `NSMutableAttributedString` then you can just set the string like this.

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 3 answer:**

```
if let attributedTitle = yourButton.attributedTitle(for: .normal) {
    let mutableAttributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedTitle)
    mutableAttributedTitle.replaceCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedTitle.length), with: "New title")
    yourButton.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedTitle, for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your attributedString:

- 'plain' attributedString:
  This means your attrString has only 1 set of attributes which apply to the entire length of the string. In this case, you can do the following:

  ```
  NSAttributedString *attrString = WHATEVER;
  NSDictionary *attributes = [attrString attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];
  NSAttributedString *newAttrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:WHATEVER
                                                                      attributes:attributes];
  ```
- your attributedString has different ranges of attributes:
  This can get really complicated depending on the structure of you attributedString, because you would have to do a lot of range handling, etc. In this case, you are better off creating a new `NSMutableAttributedString` and set the attributes from scratch.