# How to change button text in Swift Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's what I'm trying to do. If you've ever played Halo or CoD, you'd know that you could change the name of a weapon load-out.

What I'm doing is making it so you can change your load-out name using a text field. Here's the problem, the load-out name in the load-out menu is a button (to select and view info about that load-out) and I could just write this:

```
@IBAction func renameClassButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    classTopButton.text = "\(classTopTextField)"
}
```

Except it [classTopButton] is a button which doesn't allow the '.text' suffix

Answer (score 369, accepted):

You can do:

```
button.setTitle("my text here", forState: .normal)
```

Swift 3, 4, and 5:

```
button.setTitle("my text here", for: .normal)
```

Comment: Or little bit shorter. You can omit `UIControlState` part and just write like `button.setTitle("my text here", forState: .Normal)`.

Comment: I think it helps to mention: `button` is an `IBOutlet` (in contrast with the `IBAction` which contains this line of code) if you're leveraging Storyboard.

Answer (score 28):

In Xcode 8 - **Swift 3**:

`button.setTitle( "entertext" , for: .normal )`

Comment: The second argument is now `.normal` instead of `.Normal`.

Comment: Capital `.Normal` will give an error now. Undercase is now correct. `.normal`

Comment: I must say original answer was : button.setTitle( "entertext" , for: .Normal )  and it is working variant for first version of Xcode with swift 3.0 support

Answer (score 7):

It is now this For swift 3,

```
    let button = (sender as AnyObject)
    button.setTitle("Your text", for: .normal)
```

(The constant declaration of the variable is not necessary just make sure you use the sender from the button like this) :

```
    (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Your text", for: .normal)
```

Remember this is used inside the IBAction of your button.

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE:**

line

```
someButton.setTitle("New Title", forState: .normal)
```

works only when Title type is **Plain**.

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the title on a button using Attributed text, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821966/programmatically-change-attributed-title-of-uibutton/42518416

Answer (score 4):

You can Use sender argument

```
  @IBAction func TickToeButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        sender.setTitle("my text here", forState: .normal)


}
```

Comment: It is working variant for first version of Xcode with swift 3.0 support later .Normal becomes .normal

Answer (score 4):

swift 4 work as well as 3

```
libero.setTitle("---", for: .normal)
```

where libero is a uibutton

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 I tried all of this previously, but runs only:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   sender.setTitle("This is example text one", for:[])
   sender.setTitle("This is example text two", for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're using NSButton there is no `setTitle` func, instead, it's a property.

```
@IBOutlet weak var classToButton: NSButton!

. . .


classToButton.title = "Some Text"
```