# UIButton not updating?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Execute a button as follows. Button goes Gray at the start but doesn't revert to Orange at the end, why?

```
@IBAction func calculatePower(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.calculateButton.enabled = false
    self.calculateButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    self.calculateButton.titleLabel!.text = "Calculating"

    // SEVERAL HUNDREDS OF THOUSANDS OF CALCS INBETWEEN = TAKES 1 MIN

    self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    self.calculateButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.calculateButton.titleLabel!.text = "Start"

}
```

Comment: It's probably not good to have hundreds of calculations in your `IBAction`.  Why not break those out into multiple methods, verify that they are completing properly, and then go back and set the enabled state on the button?

Comment: Does the text change at the end? Does the button become enabled at the end?

Comment: No, test does not change but background colour only does, Will parse out the calcs. This was just for initial testing purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change button text in Swift Xcode 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641571/how-to-change-button-text-in-swift-xcode-6)

Comment: No it's a timing/control issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Normal State Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or

```
myButton.setTitle("Normal State Title", forState: .Normal)
```

should do the trick

Comment: It's simpler and more complex than that. What is happening is that as the intermediate func takes about a minute to execute the button it is changing the text and then putting the final, original text back so fast that you don't realise it's been changed.