# How to change the size of an SF icon in a UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, icons

Very simple question here. I'd like to change the size of an SF icon in a UIButton. I've tried doing this 20 ways to Wednesday.

1. I tried setting the EdgeInsets - no dice
2. I tried resetting the
   contentMode of the button's imageView - doesn't budge
3. Tried to change the font size of the image - wut?

There has to be a simple way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the `Default Symbol Configuration` settings on the UIButton in the `Attributes Inspector` to accomplish the same thing. All Credit to Andrew Kirna below. Thanks dude!

[image: Default Symbol Configuration]

---

Success!!! I finally figured out how to do this, thanks to a [great article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/sf-symbols-guide/) on SF Symbols. It was certainly buried in there.

It would be really nice to resize your button images in storyboard wouldn't it? I thought so at least.

1. Add IconButton.swift to your project in Xcode.

   ```
   import UIKit

   @IBDesignable
   class IconButton: UIButton {
       @IBInspectable var pointSize:CGFloat = 30.0

       override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
               let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: pointSize)
               setPreferredSymbolConfiguration(config, forImageIn: .normal)
           } else {
               // Fallback on earlier versions
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a button in storyboard with an SF icon as the image.
3. Go to the identity inspector and make the class of your button IconButton
4. Go to the attribute inspector and enter in your point size. Note that this the `height of the icon` x
   3/4. I wanted a 40 x 40 icon, so my point size was 30.
5. See your icon update in storyboard and laugh happily that you didn't spend 3 hours figuring this out :D

Some credit to the great article: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/sf-symbols-guide/

Comment: Thanks Rob. Good find! I used the "Default Symbol Configuration" settings on the UIButton in the "Attributes Inspector" to accomplish the same thing. It doesn't update in the storyboard but it works at runtime.

Answer (score 13):

This works for me (if you want it programmatically):

```
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(
    pointSize: 32, weight: .medium, scale: .default)
let image = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass", withConfiguration: config)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

This also took me forever to figure out, but the solution I eventually found (with help from [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-insert-images-into-an-attributed-string-with-nstextattachment), [Omer Tekbiyik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71112200/uibutton-font-size-isnt-changing) and [Danny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821966/programmatically-change-attributed-title-of-uibutton)) *does* in fact use the font size (bizarre, I know!) to determine the size of the button's SF symbol. After the initial setup inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, using this method makes modifying the button title attributes very straightforward, so it seems worth sharing here even though @Rob Norback and @algrid have already provided excellent answers.

Initial Setup (put this inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`):

```
let str = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "hand.tap.fill")!))
str.addAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)], range: NSRange(0..<str.length))
button.configuration?.attributedTitle = AttributedString(str)
```

To show how this can be used to modify the SF symbol later programmatically, here is the complete View Controller code, with comments included:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resizer: UISegmentedControl!
    
    var valueIsSet = false
    var clickToggle = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // viewDidLayoutSubviews is called whenever there is a change to the view hierarchy, so anything that only needs to be set once and doesn't change should be wrapped in a boolean check to avoid unnecessary reassignments when this method is called for an unrelated reason.
        if !valueIsSet {
            // This has to be NSMutableAttributedString (not NSAttributedString) in order to use the .addAttributes method on the string after initializing it.  This is how we will set the font size of the SF Symbols image.
            let str = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "hand.tap.fill")!))
            // Since the only 'character' in the string is the attachment image, the string's start and (exclusive) end indices are 0 and 1.
            // NSMutableAttributedStrings don't have a .count property, they use .length instead
            str.addAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)], range: NSRange(0..<str.length))
            // UIButtons' .titleLabels don't work reliably anymore for variants other than 'Default' (ironically named as it is no longer the default in iOS 15).  This means we should be using the new 'configuration' method to assign the attributed title.  This doesn't support assignment to NSAttributedString, only to the new AttributedString.  Fortunately, there's a wrapper:
            button.configuration?.attributedTitle = AttributedString(str)
            
            valueIsSet = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Now our button's attributed title has been initially set up (inside viewDidLayoutSubviews), it is very simple to modify it.
        // Here, the image is toggled between outline and fill versions of the same SF Symbol every time the button is clicked.
        button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.attachment = clickToggle ? NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "hand.tap")!) : NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "hand.tap.fill")!)
        clickToggle.toggle()
    }
    
    @IBAction func resizeButtonImage(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        // Changing the button's font size is as easy as changing the symbol
        button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (CGFloat(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) + 3) * 10)
    }
}
```