# UIButton font size isn't changing

Tags: swift, uikit

```
private func updateViewFromModel() {
    for index in cardButtons.indices {
        let button = cardButtons[index]
        let card = game.cards[index]
        if card.isFaceUp {
            button.setTitle(emoji(for: card), for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)
            button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        } else {
            button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = card.isMatched ? .clear : .systemIndigo
        }
        
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? title in IB is empty. I successfully set the title. but font size isn't changing.

Comment: Whats your XCode version?

Comment: These days you have to uise the crazy new "...Transformer" calls.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Xcode 13 ,UIButton has four type are `Plain,Grain,Tinted,Filled` .When you create a button in storyboard , button type automatically set with Plain that means new UIButton configurations is on. If you want to old behaviour , you must set style `plain` to `default`.

Or , If you want one of the style above . You need to set font like

```
button.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer =
   UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
     var outgoing = incoming
     outgoing.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)
     return outgoing
 }
```

Comment: Finally, an appropriate answer that works for the latest UIbutton types. Thanks much for this. But it seems they made it a little more complicated.

Comment: Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'titleTextAttributesTransformer'

Comment: Should be `configuration.titleTextAttributesTransformer`. Make sure to assign this instance of `UIButton.Configuration` to your `button.configuration`.

Comment: @Starsky *"Make sure to assign this instance..."* that's surprisingly not correct.  The whole point of the bizarre "Transformer..." calls is that they actually work in place, unlike in the old days.

Answer (score 12):

Just change button style from plain to default in storyboard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is wrong, because the behavior of the button, in many ways, is then totally different.

Answer (score 7):

Following [@Omer Tekbiyik Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71112322/458205) Note that the `titleTextAttributesTransformer` is a parameter of `UIButton.Configuration`, not `UIButton` so a possible implementation would be:

```
var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
config.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
   var outgoing = incoming
   outgoing.font = UIFont(name: "AlmoniTzarAAA", size: 20) ?? .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
   return outgoing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer transformer;
            transformer = ^(NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey, id> *incoming) {
                NSMutableDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey, id> *outgoing = [incoming mutableCopy];
                outgoing[NSFontAttributeName] = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
                return outgoing;
            };
            configuration.titleTextAttributesTransformer = transformer;
```

Comment: Why answer Obj-C? question was Swift

Comment: @soundflix Why not? Have you seen the countless Swift answers on questions tagged as Objective-C? It's the APIs that matter more. But having said that, this answer needs a lot of improvement. Code-only answers are not very helpful. A good answer explains what was wrong in the question and it explains how the answer solves the issue.